# Color list not respected

Tags: color, plot

I imposed a new color list but it is not respected in my code (that is the following). Every group of marks and the own line should have one color of the list. This is the result I have:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt]{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable, pgfplots}

\definecolor{limegreen}{rgb}{0.2, 0.8, 0.2}
\pgfplotsset{
   /pgfplots/bar  cycle  list/.style={/pgfplots/cycle  list={%
        {blue,fill=blue!30,draw=blue!50},%
        {red,fill=red!40,draw=red!60},%
        {limegreen,fill=limegreen!40,draw=limegreen!60},%
        {violet,fill=violet!30,draw=violet!50},%
     }
   },
}


\begin{filecontents*}{WHC.dat}
0   0   0   0
2   2.2 3.9 6.3
5   5.1 10.5    15.4
10  10.4    19  28
\end{filecontents*}

\newcommand{\WHCplot}[1]{
    \addplot table [only marks, x index=0, y index=#1]{WHC.dat};%
    \addplot[domain=0:10] {#1*x};%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
width=12cm, height=10cm]
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,2,3}{\WHCplot{#1}}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You are overwriting styles. Use `\addplot+[<options>]`  to append options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt]{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable, pgfplots}

\definecolor{limegreen}{rgb}{0.2, 0.8, 0.2}
\pgfplotsset{
  cycle list={%
    {blue!50,mark=square*,mark options={fill=blue!40}},%
    {red!60,mark=*,mark options={fill=red!40}},%
    {limegreen!60,mark=diamond*,mark options={fill=limegreen!40}},%
    {violet!50,mark=triangle*,mark options={fill=violet!30}},%
  }
}

\begin{filecontents*}{WHC.dat}
0   0   0   0
2   2.2 3.9 6.3
5   5.1 10.5    15.4
10  10.4    19  28
\end{filecontents*}

\newcommand{\WHCplot}[1]{
    \addplot+ table [only marks, x index=0, y index=#1]{WHC.dat};%
}
\newcommand{\WHCploti}[1]{
    \addplot+[no marks,domain=0:10] {#1*x};%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
width=12cm, height=10cm
]
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,2,3}{\WHCplot{#1}}
\pgfplotsset{cycle list shift=-3}
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,2,3}{\WHCploti{#1}}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

## Some remarks

- In your code you were setting an style `bar  cycle  list/.style` and never using it. I directly changed to `cycle list={...}`.
- In `cycle list={}` you specify colors, line styles, marks and mark styles.
- You need `\addplot+` since you are using [] for your `\addplot`s.
- Since each group (marks and lines) should receive the same color I used two loops and  `\pgfplotsset{cycle list shift=-3}`. If this was not intended, please return to the settings you had with just one loop.